# Excel - Column chart labels as percentages of the highest bar

Tags: excel, charts, ms-office

I'd like to add a label to my Graph. However I want the highest value to be set as 100%, and all other values to be a percentage of that value.

For example:

```
FirstSeries  1000
SecondSeries 500
ThirdSeries  100
```

Is there a way to add labels to columns, so the second and third column would show percentages of the highest value (1000). So in this case, data label for second column would be 50%, and for the third 10%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create a new column for data labels and use this [addin](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm)